# 'Timer' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to build a simple timer in C# and [used this website for reference](http://markashleybell.com/creating-a-simple-stopwatchtimer-application-with-c-windows-forms.html) initially, but kept receiving an error twice in the application for the two lines:

```
private Timer _timer;

_timer = new Timer();
```

Initially, in my application, I tried ...

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new Timer();
```

When I did this, C# didn't recognize tick, start, or stop as methods.  Finally, I copied and pasted the author's code into my application just to see if I could get the timer to run and then work backwards, and I received the same errors on the same two lines.  Most of what I've read online say to initialize the timer by the System.Timers.Timer route, but that leads to more errors and I don't see those methods that the author uses as available following that route.

**Update:** If I add `using System.Windows.Forms.Timer;` to the top of my file, I still receive the same error messages.

**Note:** currently my code is a copy-and-paste of the author's code, which he asserts as working, but doesn't.

Comment: `Timer` in the author's code refers to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, so it appears you don't have the same `using` directives at the top of your file.

Comment: And use a better namespace name, don't call it "Timer".

Comment: And as stated at the end of the article: you can read up on the differences in [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to create a timer. This is a windows forms timer. There is also a Windows Threading timer that you can create.

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr;

    private void timerCallBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void createTimer()
    {
        tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        tmr.Interval = 1000;
        tmr.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timerCallBack);
    }
```

Comment: If I use this, when I later try to "start" the timer, it asserts that the object reference not set to an instance of an object.  This doesn't actually initialize a timer, otherwise, it would start.

Comment: use the tmr.Start(); to start it. Sorry forgot you also need to declare the speed at which the timer fires. Try the above.

Comment: You would need to call `createTimer` to initialize the timer before attempting to call `tmr.Start()`, or `tmr` will be a null reference.

Comment: Yes that should be known without saying it though.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `System.Timers.Timer` to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, Change this to `Timer _timer = new Timer();` and add `using System.Windows.Forms.Timer;` to top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same type of error once. The reason for my error was that The name of my project was Stopwatch and thus the namespace created for the project was also named Stopwatch which the compiler happened to recognize over the **System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch** class which I was trying to access.

So when I was trying to create an object of the **System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch** class I was getting an error **'Stopwatch' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'** even though that I had included **using System.Diagnostics**

Later I realized that the compiler is identifying the Stopwatch namespace, which was the namespace of the project which I was working on over the **System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch** class.

So make sure that you did not make this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `using System.Windows.Forms.Timer;` will not work; as the resulting compiler error message will inform you, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is a type, not a namespace.

You will need to add `using System.Windows.Forms;` (note, no `Timer`) or explicitly define each `Timer` instance as a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` as suggested by deathismyfriend:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
```

I've just updated [the solution I linked from the article](https://github.com/markashleybell/mab_stopwatch_spike/archive/1.0.zip) to a VS2010 solution, so if you're still having problems I'd suggest you download, compile and run it and then carefully compare that code with your own.